# Opening multiple pages at once with one script

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, window.open

I have this code below, I want to open all the pages the user checks, but only one opens right now.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="site1" name="site1" value="site1">site1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="site2" name="site2" value="site2">site2
    <input name="submit" value="check" type="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

And for the script:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('site1').checked) {
        window.open('http://www.site1.com');
    } else {

    }
}
```

I now have it all in separate scripts maybe there is another way?

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('site2').checked) {
        window.open('http://www.site2.com');
    } else {

    }
}
```

Your answer will be appreciated!

Comment: you can't declare the same function twice. Really not clear what you are doing. What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: Look at the comment below. The messy code has been fixed but the "opening multiple pages" has not yet been

Comment: perhaps browser have limits on how quickly you can open numerous windows. Could try setting a delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all the selected checkboxes and call `window.open`.

```
function validate() {
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var sitename = $(this).val();
        window.open('http://www.' + sitename + '.com');
    });
    return false; // Prevent form submission
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qPV7E/3/)

Comment: The code is now much cleaner but the same problem persists.

Comment: I wont open all the pages if multiple checkboxes are selected

Comment: My browser was blocking the pop-ups it said... Thanks very much sir!